# Email notification in jenkins ios build fails

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, auto-build

When I try to build an iOS App with Jenkins , I got the error in Email notification for Office365 but for gmail I am able to get notification.

Error message:

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was
>   not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Comment: This is caused by TLS is not enabled. Try adding java property for Jenkins on jenkins start: `-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true`. Check this post to see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966237/jenkins-and-office365-email-notification-settings

Comment: For which file of jenkins do we need to add ?

Comment: No file need, just add as the command line parameter. For example, if you start your jenkins using command `java -jar jenkins.war`, then you can add the param like `java -jar jenkins.war -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true`

Comment: Though I added that line while starting , Still getting the same issue **MainFramer** , Please help . I have installed jenkins on same user instead of seperate jenkins user