# Jenkins email notification error when jenkins.war is deployed in tomcat webapps folder?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops

I am using Jenkins by deploying Jenkins.war in webapps folder. I can't able send email notifications and searched for solution, and then try to implement the steps mentioned in this link:[Jenkins and Office365 email notification settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966237/jenkins-and-office365-email-notification-settings) . Where can I found Jenkins.xml file In this case, where should I add  this **JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"**

Comment: Are you using simple shell execution, scripted pipeline or declarative pipeline? Also, Do you need a success, failure or starting mail?

Comment: I am not using shell execution or scripted pipeline or declarative pipeline. I Just configured E-mail Notification and tried to Test configuration by sending test e-mail

Comment: Could you share us an screenshot of your configurations?

Comment: If you are just testing the email notification, please delete the "deploy, amazon" words of your question. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Use email extension plugin [Link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

Answer (score 0):

In bin\catalina.sh of your tomcat installation you can set:

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true